# Datatables - Jquery click event isn't called for buttons loaded into the table through Ajax Source/Ajax Reload

Tags: ajax, datatables

I have loaded my JQuery and Datatables code correctly into the page. My data is loaded from the sAjaxSource option in the Datatables initialisation function.

I am loading buttons into the cells that have classes and IDs that the should allow JQuery to fire functions when clicked. As the Datatable uses pagination, only the first page works, as I load the JQuery click function as a function call once the Datatable has initialised (using fnInitComplete).

I suffered a previous issue and realised that I had to load the data into the HTML before initialising the Datatable, and all calls to the JQuery click function worked, but that was using HTML table data, not data from an Ajax Source.

In short, my JQuery click functions aren't running on elements loaded into the table through AjaxSource. (FYI, my click functions are trying to reload different data into the table, and after the first reload, no click events work at all, so I am worried that my second issue will be getting the click events to run after that too). My code is below.

```
<script src="fnReloadAjax.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

            //Any table related events need to go in here so that it initialises post data load
            function tableInit() {
                $('.myButton').click(function() {
                    oTable.fnReloadAjax('mySource2.php');
                });
            }

            var oTable;
            oTable = $("#taskTable").dataTable({ bSort: true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": 'mySource1.php',
                bAutoWidth: true,
                "iDisplayLength": 5, "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 100], // can be removed for basic 10 items per page
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1, 0]}],
                "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
                    tableInit();
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jquery's traditional event handling doesn't work for dynamically added content. You should use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Instead of this :

```
function tableInit() 
{
    $('.myButton').click(function() {
            oTable.fnReloadAjax('mySource2.php');
        });
}
```

you should do this :

```
function tableInit() 
{
    $('anyParentSelector').on('click','.myButton',function() {
        oTable.fnReloadAjax('mySource2.php');
    });
}
```

Note that I did put "anyParentSelector" , it could be `body` or even `document`, but best-practices advises it to be the most direct static parent of your dynamically created `.myButton` elements. This for performance reasons...

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks.